# Importance of templates?

Tags: c++

From a game developing point of view, how important do you consider templates to be as a topic to know about in C++? Have you used templates as a part of developing games or similar? Neither do I really understand how important templates can be considered from a *general* point of view.

Comment: Templates are a language-level feature of C++. It is as important to game development as it is to any other application.

Comment: @Philipp There is the widespread idea that game programming requires a different subset of programming language features than other programming does, so I think the question is relevant. Note that this comment doesn't endorse that idea.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 aspects:

- Consuming meta-programming, i.e. using templates written by others: The STL (Standard TEMPLATE Library) is a pillar of C++. Nowadays, developing a large C++ application - that includes most games - without using template classes like `vector<>` or `shared_ptr<>` means the developer doesn't know how to program in C++.
- Producing meta-programming, i.e. writing templates: Oftentimes, one can get away without writing templates (often using polymorphism instead) by sacrificing a bit of performance, type safety, or both. If you want cutting edge performance, you need templates, if you don't, you can skip them. Additionally, due to the added type safety provided by templates, their use is strongly recommended if you write a library or other complex components that are to be used by others, as proper use of templates can make your interfaces easy to use right and hard to use wrong. In larger teams, it's common that some people write most of the template code, while most others merely use the templates.

Overall, if you don't want to write templates, C++ may not be the best programming language to chose. If you don't want the highest performance, you could use something like C# instead, unless you're choosing C++ because you're more familiar with the language. Yet if you're not familiar with templates, you're not familiar with C++. There are still plenty of valid reasons to chose C++ regardless, e.g. licensing, corporate constraints, supported target architectures, pre-existing libraries, etc.

Comment: "If you don't want the highest performance, you could use something like C# " - but can't templates also lead to worse performance, such as from compilation-time and size? In that case, isn't that statement incorrect? Btw. thank you so much for the answer (same for all the other nice persons who are willing to help)!

Comment: @step Compile time doesn't impact the performance of the resulting binaries, if that's what you're worried about. While template heavy code generally takes longer to compile, if you want to optimize compile time you should avoid C++ altogether.

Comment: When you hate templates, then C# might not be the best refuge for you. [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx) is  different name for a very similar feature with a very similar syntax.

Comment: Oh, I love templates - they are smart! I just do not encounter them much in the game industry, which is starting to get odd if templates really are as useful as I am starting to understand.

Comment: @Philipp While they look similar on the surface, they are completely different from the viewpoint of a library writer. The most glaring difference is that generics are not touring complete. Ironically, that means generics are mere code templates, while templates allow generic coding.

Comment: @Philipp I disagree -- generics (whether in Java or C#) borrow the syntax from templates, but lack most of the features, in particular duck typing. In practice, they are pretty much two completely separate things.

Comment: One of the reasons I think big engines sometimes don't use templates that much in their APIs is because they're often aiming for interop with other languages. In that case the code generation doesn't help that much at least at an interface level since other languages can't utilize a class template or function template to generate the same C++ code ,e.g. So often APIs tend to lean more towards dynamic polymorphism instead of static, and often more towards C than C++ since C is considerably more standardized for interop and ABI.

Comment: IMO that's the biggest weakness of C++ over C, e.g., is when it comes to providing a software development kit, e.g. At that point if you want to interop with other languages, exposing templates doesn't work. Even if you want to target C++ plugins only, then we can't publicly use `std::vector`, for example, since the plugin writer's implementation might differ from yours in incompatible ways. We can't throw exceptions in exported functions, since it's not safe to throw across module boundaries to plugins built against different compilers and settings...

Comment: Similar thing for virtual functions/vtables, type info with RTTI, etc. It's one of the things I wish there was more focus on, since otherwise I'd be able to use C++ features a whole lot more often.

Comment: Its probably more important to understand what they do. There are many examples of templates being good and bad. Templates can generate repetitive code that can bloat your exe where a function call would be quicker and reduce the exe size. They can also generate zero code and provide type safety and readability. If you can understanding what they actually do then you can use then wisely.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are a crucial part of C++, they enable flexibility and expressiveness without sacrificing type-safety or efficiency. They are C++'s implementation of generic programming.

They don't have any specific relationship to game development, but like all the other tools in the box they come in handy when you need them. They are typically more useful in "engine"-flavoured tasks, which need their characteristics, and less prominent in the gameplay code which sits on top and doesn't need to be fast or generic (that's also the part that can be written with a scripting language to get other benefits instead).

For an example, [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/136050/46420) is one of my answers about implementing a kind of component-based dispatching system. You can see that I've used templates extensively (and a hint of macros as well) to create a generic system, and then used it to write terser gameplay code.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are especially useful for containers or similar types. Since you understand templates *generally* I will omit an explanation of them, and rather give an example instead.

Templates can be useful in game development (other than for simple containers) when using patterns like the [object pool](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html) pattern, especially for particle pools. You might want to reuse the implementation for an object pool for different kinds of objects, like enemies, particles, or props. (The linked example does not use templates, but explains the pattern well.)

However, since this is mostly used for optimizing, it is mostly dependant whether one uses an engine that already abstracts instancing functionality, or one even wants to write a custom game engine, in which case it might be inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by 'from a games development point of view'. I've developed games without using templates at all. I've worked for companies which insist on using the standard template library and encourage using templates as well as companies which ban stl & templates completely! If you would like to work in games development then its a good idea to understand them. When abused they can bloat code and make it less readable. Understanding their potential pitfalls is quite important.